# How to center input field?

Tags: html, css

I'm not so good with using display values to organize forms, it would be great if you would give me an example of being able to organize in an up-to-date way.

I'm making a login/register system, and I want to center the input fields in the div. Here's the code of the login form:-

```
<body style='font-family: Times New Roman, verdana, sans-serif;'>
    <div style='width: 70%; padding 10px; border: 5px solid #316ED6; background-color: #648CD1; color: #31D8EB; margin: auto; text-align: center;'>
        <h1>Register Now!</h1>
        <br />
        <form action='' method='post'/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Username:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Password:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Re-enter Password</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='passsword' name='passwordconfirm' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>First and Last Name:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='name' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='submit' name='register' value='Complete Registration'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <h4>Already own a Connection account? Login <a href='index.php'>Here!</a></h4>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use html <center> </center> tag to center the input fields in div

Comment: You want to center input fields with their labels?

Comment: @Jahid26 The `<center>` element is deprecated

Comment: you could just add this css rule to your table.

table{
     margin:0 auto;
}

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: Can you tell me why give me down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest possible is to give the form `display: inline-block`.

Setting `text-align: left;` on the `table` will control the `label`s text alignment

```html
<body style='font-family: Times New Roman, verdana, sans-serif;'>
    <div style='width: 70%; padding 10px; border: 5px solid #316ED6; background-color: #648CD1; color: #31D8EB; margin: auto; text-align: center;'>
        <h1>Register Now!</h1>
        <br />
        <form action='' method='post' style="display: inline-block" />
            <table style="text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Username:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Password:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Re-enter Password</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='passsword' name='passwordconfirm' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>First and Last Name:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='name' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='submit' name='register' value='Complete Registration' style="width: 100%"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <h4>Already own a Connection account? Login <a href='index.php'>Here!</a></h4>
    </div>
</body>
```

*Side note:*

*By updating the last `tr` like this, you'll get a nice positioned button too*

```
<tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='submit' name='register' value='Complete Registration' style="width: 100%"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just add a css rule to your table

```
    table{
         margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to do this is to use the center tag `<center> </center>`

I edited your code to center the entire form.

```
<body style='font-family: Times New Roman, verdana, sans-serif;'>
    <div style='width: 70%; padding 10px; border: 5px solid #316ED6; background-color: #648CD1; color: #31D8EB; margin: auto; text-align: center;'>
        <h1>Register Now!</h1>
        <br />
        <center>
        <form action='' method='post'/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Username:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Password:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Re-enter Password</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='passsword' name='passwordconfirm' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>First and Last Name:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='name' style='padding: 4px'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='submit' name='register' value='Complete Registration'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        </center>
        <h4>Already own a Connection account? Login <a href='index.php'>Here!</a></h4>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

snippet below

```css
form{
  text-align:center;
}
#form_table{
display:inline-table;
}
```

```html
<body style='font-family: Times New Roman, verdana, sans-serif;'>
  <div style='width: 70%; padding 10px; border: 5px solid #316ED6; background-color: #648CD1; color: #31D8EB; margin: auto; text-align: center;' id="meta_container">
    <h1>Register Now!</h1>
    <br />
    <form action='' method='post'/>
    <table id="form_table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <b>Username:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' name='username' style='padding: 4px' />
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <b>Password:</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='password' name='password' style='padding: 4px' />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <b>Re-enter Password</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='passsword' name='passwordconfirm' style='padding: 4px' />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <b>First and Last Name:</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type='text' name='name' style='padding: 4px' />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type='submit' name='register' value='Complete Registration' />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <h4>Already own a Connection account? Login <a href='index.php'>Here!</a></h4>
  </div>
</body>
```